# Change behavior of angular-ui typeahead on demand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I use [typeahead](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead/docs) (by angular-ui) that has an `typeahead-editable` attribute which decides if typeahead should restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only. I want to toggle this behavior when a $scope variable changes value.

```
typeahead-editable="{{ allowEdit }}"
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't update after it has been initialized.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

**Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9daKQhIo2YusRBreYnmQ?p=preview)!**

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have updated my question with a link to a plunker.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question:) Check the source code, it seems this binding is done only once https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js  "var isEditable = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadEditable) !== false;"